# Google Maps API Directions Service route details (warnings)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[image]

I can't seem to find the option from google.maps.DirectionService API docs to include the warning messages display similar to Google Maps Directions. Are there any properties I should include that I might have miss out?

Currently I only include travelMode: DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING and provideRouteAlternatives: true in my request, and the waypoints are setup correctly cause I am able to get the correct route suggestions, distance, and duration in my request.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Each `route` object that you get in the response contains an array of `warnings`.

> **`warnings`** Type: `Array<string>` Warnings to be displayed when showing these directions.

[Reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsRoute).

That said, I just tried a few routes where Google Maps websites gives some warnings and the same Directions request through the API returns an empty `warnings` array.

**Edit:**

After trying at least 15 routes, with `provideRouteAlternatives: true` and checking each route, the `warnings` array never contained anything. That looks like a bug... I will investigate.

Comment: yup the warnings property was where I was expecting the response, but it always returned empty that's why I wasn't sure. If it is a bug I hope it can be resolve soon.

Comment: I have created a [new issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116831644) so it should be clarified soon (fixed... you never know when).